# Pgpool configuration with Liferay cluster

Tags: database, cluster, liferay, postgresql

I'm using a Liferay cluster connected to pgpool2 and when I run heavy user activity against the web servers I see a lot of exceptions regarding liferay unable to establish a connection to the DB. There are two DBs behind pgpool

Exception examples

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
----------
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: A ResourcePool cannot acquire a new resource -- the factory or source appears to be down.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:152)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:211)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveInteger4(PGStream.java:289)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:282)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    ... 14 more
------
02:34:55,197 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->Q5VpVuN8]-HelperThread-#0][BasicResourcePool:894] Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@427db1c2 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
```

I have liferay setup to use C3p0, and the db I configured is to pgpool2.  I've been playing with this for days now, trying a zillion combinations and I think I'm in the best state but still not there yet and I'm no DBA.  Liferay is configured with the same user/pass so I think pgpool would reuse the cached connection but I can't pinpoint the problem.  Here's my configs

postgres config

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 100MB
```

pgpool2 config

```
num_init_children = 500
max_pool = 10
child_max_connections = 4950
child_life_time = 300
connection_life_time = 0
client_idle_limit = 0
```

Liferay config

```
jdbc.default.acquireIncrement=5
jdbc.default.acquireRetryAttempts=3
jdbc.default.acquireRetryDelay=1000
jdbc.default.connectionCustomizerClassName=com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.pool.c3p0.PortalConnectionCustomizer
jdbc.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=60
jdbc.default.maxIdleTime=3600
jdbc.default.maxPoolSize=1000
jdbc.default.minPoolSize=10
jdbc.default.numHelperThreads=100
```

Should I be increasing max_connections on my DB servers behind pgpool? Or change the pgpool params to something like

```
num_init_children = 10
max_pool = 500
child_max_connections = 4950
connection_life_time = 0
client_idle_limit = 0
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From [pgpool-II user manual](http://pgpool.projects.pgfoundry.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html)

```
max_pool*num_init_children <= (max_connections - superuser_reserved_connections)
```

If you need 500 concurrent connections to pgpool then you need even more `max_connections` in your Postgres config. So for 500 concurrent connections you'd need:

In `pgpool.conf`:

```
num_init_children = 500
max_pool = 1 # there's no need for more if you don't use different credentials
```

In `postgresql.conf`:

```
max_connections = 550
```

---

Also - I don't think you should use C3PO and PgPool-II - it does not make sense to stack two connection poolers on each other. Also [I don't think that you should use more than one database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59495/9060).